# Is it ok to cut tree branches with a jigsaw?

Tags: pruning, safety, branches

I know it probably sounds silly. The idea is to cut the branch off the trees with proper tools (tree pruner, pole saw or whatever), that's easy, takes a minute. What is not so time-friendly, is cutting up the branches that are already on the ground. I need them to be in small and manageable pieces to fit in bags so it can be taken away economically as "green waste". I have no intention of buying a chipper at the moment. A chainsaw is overkill, and I wouldn't want to buy a reciprocating saw just for this. For really small branches I'd use secateurs or loppers. Whenever loppers are necessary, and around 2.5-5cm in branch diameter I think it would be faster to use my battery-powered jigsaw.

For example, I have this blade: [Bosch t144df](https://www.boschtools.com/ca/en/boschtools-ocs/t-shank-jig-saw-blades-for-wood-t144df-29837-p/)

If it's not such a good idea, why?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do this for two reasons:

1. Safety: the jigsaw is going to want to jump around and green wood is like a spring.
2. The blade on a jigsaw is designed for seasoned wood.  Blades for green wood have a different design.

I would recommend a [bow saw](https://www.google.com/search?q=bow%20saw&source=lnms&tbm=isch).  You be able to cut branches of that size with a few strokes.  You can even cut down small trees with them.  A pruning saw would also work but I generally prefer the bow for something not attached to the tree.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a (cheap) small saw. This is a lot more handy for pruning, and you can also cut relatively large branches (it is slow, but sometime I prefer this method instead of chainsaw).

Use your force, luke!